# Which is one of the best format to store a large dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with ~127000000 observations and 5 columns.

It looks like this:

```
structure(list(species = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Aa achalensis", 
"Aa argyrolepis", "Aa aurantiaca", "Aa calceata", "Aa colombiana", 
"Aa denticulata", "Aa erosa"), class = "factor"), establishment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "dark", class = "factor"), 
    region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "USA", class = "factor"), 
    height = c(0.348046463, 0.265755867, 0.382584479, 0.336147631, 
    0.333343259, 0.333343259, 0.382584479), resitance = c(-0.3906, 
    -0.6257, -0.2987, -0.423, -0.4307, -0.4307, -0.2987)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I tried to save it as .csv but it didn't work. I also increase the memory.limit(size=56000) but it also didn't help.

Is there a way that I can do this task? Another format? I am beginner in R.

Thank you all very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? Do you want to save the contents of the `data.frame` to disk? *"I tried to save it as .csv but it didn't work."* Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Hi Dunois. Sure. I tried to save the contents of the data.frame using write.csv(df,"df.csv", col.names = T) but it stopped during the process and didn't create the csv expected. Maybe due to its size?

Comment: Use `fwrite` from package data.table.

Comment: Really denpends on what you are saving it for. If it is as a backup or to share it with other R users. then `.rds` is probably the best format. `.csv`'s are fairly inefficient, do not preserve anything other than basic types and do are not have a clearly defined standard. You should only use them, when you are unsure what software your audience runs, as it can be opened in basically any data analysis software

Comment: I want to share it later with my supervisor. By doing df=fwrite(df, file = "", sep = ",") and also fwrite(df, file = "", sep = ",") it didn't go to my directory neither global environmental. Also compress = FALSE is not storing my df. Can you provide me a code?

Comment: With `fwrite(df, file = "filename.csv", sep = ",")` or with `readr::write_csv(x = df, file = "filename.csv")` you should get the csv file in your current working directory. You can find your current working directory with `getwd()`. If it doesn't work, please report the exact error message you receive.